# Tracking manual testing interaction

Tags: manual-testing, tools, gui

I'm looking for some piece of software that allows me to track interaction during manual testing to log what was tested (which elements were clicked, what was written to the input, etc).

Use case:

1. Start this tool
2. Execute some manual testing
3. Stop this tool and generate report (maybe with screenshots) -
   .xmind, .xml, .txt, doesn't really matter

I tried to wrap psr (windows utility) in C#, but our tested application is half Windows MFC and half web app in chromium, so PSR didn't handle chromium window well (it didn't recognized single web elements).
Can you recommend me a tool, that works with both technologies?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of test tracking tools or test case management tools,

Some SaS ( pay by user)

- [TestRail](http://www.gurock.com/testrail/)
- [TestLodge](http://www.testlodge.com/)

Some one off purchases

- [Microsoft Test Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635157.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [SoftBear Test Complete](http://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/)

Some FreeWare

- [MozTrap](https://moztrap.mozilla.org/)

As with any software selection, carefully consider why you want to use the product and what you want it to help you achieve.  All those I have provided as examples allow you to manage your manual tests (and import them to get you started).  You can then "run" your suites and keep track of tests you have / have not completed.  As you requested, they will all make you pretty reports to report back to the boss!

If you want to "track" your tests then SmartBear's and Microsoft's solutions allow you to record your actions.  There is often a (large) cost associated with the functionality but I would actually recommend you attempt to outline your tests Then follow them to ensure they are repeatable, but again, evaluate the various options and select the one best suited to your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) and record macros as you test. If it were web browser only, using [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/)'s click-and-record would be just fine. In the past I have also kept [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler2) running as I tested. Those logs can be packaged and added to the tickets for the developers to comb over.

Comment: This is a good answer. Many test automation tools have a Record feature. Their output scripts can provide a decent log of what was tested. I use WinTask, but you could certain try a bunch and see which works best for you. This might help: http://www.allthingsquality.com/2013/08/free-trial-versions-of-commercial-test.html

Answer (score 1):

I havent't used it myself, yet, but I recently stumbled across TimeSnapper (http://timesnapper.com/). It's a small windows app which runs in the background and takes a screenshot every few seconds. You can also ad notes. When you're done you can play back your session.

Comment: I have used TimeSnapper. It would be fine for the "screenshots" part, but doesn't actually "log" what is tested.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to Microsoft Test Manager as Luca suggested you can try uPerform (http://www.ancile.com/products/uperform-software/overview).  It's pretty easy to pick up and run with.  Not sure if there's a free version floating around, but my company provided it once and I still play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you write C# code you probably already use Visual Studio, if so evaluate Microsoft Test Manager because it is fully integrated with Visual Studio and Team Foundation Server. Microsoft Test Manager has a dedicated set of features for running and managing manual tests with the possibility to import stack traces directly from your builds.

Alternatively you could consider Telerik Test Studio.